# awk - вырезать весь столбец с длинными числами и их разделить

Tags: linux, список, awk

```
cat text.txt | awk '{$3=$3/10000000000; print}' > result.txt
```

вырезаю третий столбец из текстового документа, в котором длинные целые положительные числа (максимально 20 знаков) :

```
11367086573885593600
10334651978543290368
10197533251863449600
```

как сделать, чтобы при делении чисел на 10000000000 выдавало не

```
1.13671e+09
1.03347e+09
1.01975e+09
```

а выдавало :

```
1136708657.3885593600
1033465197.8543290368
1019753325.1863449600
```

если в awk так нельзя, то как сделать отдельно по-другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант (вероятно не самый лучший) можно считать с помощью `dc`:

```
cat text.txt | awk '{print $3 " 10000000000 / p"}' | dc -e '10 k' -f -
```

`dc` — калькулятор с обратной польской записью и произвольной десятичной точностью. В большинстве дистрибутивов GNU/Linux является частью пакета `bc`.

Команда `k` устанавливает точность.
Команда `/` делит два числа в стеке.
Команда `p` печатает число.

---

Для значений меньше единицы `dc` не выводит ведущий ноль, AFAIK нормального способа заставить его выводить числа в таком формате, который хочется нет, но можно добавить в конвейер ещё один универсальный молоток, 
`sed`:

```
sed 's/^\./0./'
```

или `awk` (дабы не зависеть от двух утилит):

```
awk '{sub("^\\.", "0&"); print $0}'
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Вот только 0 потерялся впереди перед точкой, если число менее 1.0 Это как-то лечится?

Comment: @Bl0wfish, добавил в ответ.